# Using Excel XLSX as configuration file, how to read it fastest from .NET 4.x

Tags: .net, excel

I am using Excel as a user editor for software configuration files, think tables of configuration data for the software. I use extensive validation before the configuration is used in the software (an Office VSTO .NET addin for Visio).

Unfortunately reading the file via Excel automation is slooooooooooooooooooooow, exporting to CSV makes for superfast reading if the config but then I end up with a file for every worksheet.

Much better is to read the Excel file, no interim steps that complicate the process, but what is the fastest way to do so?

I do not need to write to the config file, only read it. If the validation of the config data fails the entire configuration is rejected until the user/admin fixes the data by hand and tries to re-read the Excel file.

I do not use any of the special features of Excel (Charts etc etc), the only special things I'd like to read (another advantage over working with multiple CSV files):

- The color of certain cells
- The name of certain cells

Thank you for sharing your knowledge and experience!

Comment: Why not VBA a solution to export as JSON or CSV as one file. That way you keep the easily maintained excel file but get the benefit of speed with CSV/JSON.

Comment: Thank you that is a possibility, I do realize that if I make an Excel VSTO addin with a JSON export I could validate the input from Excel before saving the JSON file, which ensures that the JSON file is always prevalidated.

Comment: Yes. And you can set it up however you want and is not limited in to any library bugs or limitations. (It doesn't have to be a addin, you can just make the file claim/clan)

Comment: Flipping autocorrect .... You can just make the file xlsm/xlsb